# How do I set a dynamically created component equal to a manually create component? Setting the location equal, isn't accurate because of container?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, dynamically-generated

When I try to set a dynamically created rich text box at runtime and set the location equal to that of a manually created control, the location isn't the same, it's slightly off. I guess because of the container throwing it off? This is my code, but it's not being set to the exact same location. How do I fix this?

```
  RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
  rtb.Location = linkLabel.Location;
```

This doesnt work accurately.

Comment: Are you adding your new RichTextBox to the Controls collection of a Container? If you are (at some point), the *exact same location* is evaluated *visually*, or are you reading the location of the two Controls and you find that *it's off* because you read two different `Point` values? -- Have you considered the borders and the padding?

Comment: it's visually off and the point is off too, when i debug the location of the instantiated control its not the same as the non dynamic one i set it equal too. Its off by like 50 points or so.

Comment: When are you adding `rtb` to a parent Container? Show the full code. -- *It's off by like 50 points*: you mean 50 pixels. When and what are you comparing when you get this measure? Show that code, too.

Comment: so i tried setting the parent of the textbox before doing the ```Controls.Add()```, but when I did ```mytextbox.Parent =  myPanel;``` after the controls add it worked. So i guess it was setting the main form as the parent when i added the textbox as a control. So guess i have to just set the parent after doing the ```Controls.Add```

Comment: @dutoit077 `Controls.Add` is synonymous with `this.Controls.Add`. You should be doing `myPanel.Add(mytextbox)`.

Comment: is setting the parent of rtb to myPanel the same as doing ```myPanel.Add(mytextbox)```?

Comment: In this context, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a control via code you need to add it to a container, if you for example use panels, all controls ontop of a panel will have their own location (0;0 represents the left-top of the panel for example).
So if you do not use panels go with this:

```
  RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
  this.Controls.Add(rtb); //If your linklabel is ontop of a panel, use panelName.Controls.Add
  rtb.Location = linkLabel.Location;
```